# Remember cursor position on file reload

Tags: cursor, html, reload

I want to remember my cursor position when refresh the page.but whenever i refresh the page the cursor can top of the page.how can i solve it.any help appreciated.thanks

Comment: This question makes no sense without an actual case. Missing scripts? What you tried?

Comment: The cursor always remains in the same position even how many times a page is refreshed (provided that you don't move your mouse).

Answer (score 2):

You could use ajax. Get the cursor-coordinates (although I think you're after the scrollbar position) and post them to your page (by $_GET). Then post them back and use javascript to position the page to where-ever you want it.

[Get scrollbar info](https://www.google.nl/#hl=nl&gs_nf=1&tok=tpBust4g6LCZUHsIJUHRgg&cp=16&gs_id=1s&xhr=t&q=get+scrollbar+position&pf=p&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&oq=get+scrollbar+po&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=1b5ef110c32c7bfa&biw=1920&bih=935),
[Set scrollbar](https://www.google.nl/#hl=nl&sclient=psy-ab&q=set+scrollbar+position&oq=set+scrollbar+position&gs_l=hp.3..0j0i7i30j0i30j0i10i30.24083.24332.2.24981.3.3.0.0.0.1.116.250.2j1.3.0...0.0...1c.1.86PQNRQmGbU&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=1b5ef110c32c7bfa&biw=1920&bih=935)

Comment: Pretty complicated solution for a simple problem. Sometimes things have to be done this way.

Comment: ben you are right....i have a facebook type application which i want to make a comment in some post .......when i make comment and refresh the page the page will be top of the page

Comment: hey i fount this pls check this. is it valid solution or not?http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/printthread.php?t=310608